# Python Memory Error when running nltk classifier

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory, classification, nltk

I am running a classifier over a large amount of text, which is causing then problem with the memory error.  Python gets to about 2gb Memory use and then returns the error.

I know that loading such a lot of data and then trying to process it is causing the error, I just don't know a work around, I'm very new to python.  I guess I would need to "chunk" the text input or process the text line by line but again I'm unsure about how to actually implement this in the code that I have.  Any help would be amazing.

The Code:

```
import nltk, pickle
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


customstopwords = []

p = open('', 'r')
postxt = p.readlines()

n = open('', 'r')
negtxt = n.readlines()

neglist = []
poslist = []

for i in range(0,len(negtxt)):
    neglist.append('negative')

for i in range(0,len(postxt)):
    poslist.append('positive')

postagged = zip(postxt, poslist)
negtagged = zip(negtxt, neglist)

print "STAGE ONE" 

taggedtweets = postagged + negtagged

tweets = []

for (word, sentiment) in taggedtweets:
    word_filter = [i.lower() for i in word.split()]
    tweets.append((word_filter, sentiment))

def getwords(tweets):
    allwords = []
    for (words, sentiment) in tweets:
            allwords.extend(words)
    return allwords

def getwordfeatures(listoftweets):
    wordfreq = nltk.FreqDist(listoftweets)
    words = wordfreq.keys()
    return words

wordlist = [i for i in getwordfeatures(getwords(tweets)) if not i in stopwords.words('english')]
wordlist = [i for i in getwordfeatures(getwords(tweets)) if not i in customstopwords]

print "STAGE TWO"

def feature_extractor(doc):
    docwords = set(doc)
    features = {}
    for i in wordlist:
        features['contains(%s)' % i] = (i in docwords)
    return features

print "STAGE THREE"

training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(feature_extractor, tweets)

print "STAGE FOUR"

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

print "STAGE FIVE"      

f = open('my_classifier.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(classifier, f)
f.close()
```

Comment: if you're on windows and running a 32 bit python - that's your problem, and it does crash at a little less than 2GB usually. you can get more memory available by moving to a 64 bit python.

Comment: downloaded and attempting now

Comment: seems to have sorted it although I guess it might not be the best way, spiked at 3GB of memory if anyone cares.